# Thirdparty Oauth2 in Angular 2 gives "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present" error

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, passport-facebook

I have been trying to implement facebook Oauth2 in my website which is using angular 2 on the client and node/express/passport on the server.

In my login componet, I rely on an auth.service injectable containing a `thirdPartyAuth()` function:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor(private http:Http){}

    thirdPartyAuth(){
        return this.http.get('/auth/facebook')
        .toPromise()
        .then(user => user.json())
    }
}
```

My routes file on the server contains two routes: '/auth/facebook' and '/auth/facebook/callback'

```
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: ['email'] }));

app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', function(req, res, next){
    passport.authenticate('facebook', function(err, user, info){
        if (err) {return next(err);}
        if (!user) {return res.send(info);}

        req.logIn(user, function(err){
            if (err) { return next(err);}
            res.send(user);
        })
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

However, when I execute, I get this error:
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%…%3A3000%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=email&client_id=598179497025719. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.`

I read about CORS and tried appending a header to the response sent by the 'auth/facebook/callback' route to no avail:

```
req.logIn(user, function(err){
                if (err) { 
                    return next(err); 
                }
                res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','http://localhost:3000');//Appending a header
                res.send(user); //json containing the user profile
```

Alternatively, if I use `location.href = "http://www.localhost:3000/auth/facebook"` in `thirdPartyAuth()`, I avoid the error and facebook auth is successful, but I don't know how to handle the json object sent back by `res.send(user)` line which ends up displaying in the browser.

Comment: Maybe this API is not supposed to be used from the client, but only from a server.